# Calabash console Android - query get all ids on screen

Tags: calabash, calabash-android, calabash-ios

In Calabash console for iOS there is a command:

```
ids
```

The command displays all the element ids on the current screen.

For Android you can use command

```
query("*")
```

Which displays all the views on screen, you can manually look through and find the ids.

But what is the Android equivalent command for just displaying ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Calabash equivalent command:

```
query("*",:id)
```